# Emitting sound at a particular frequency in phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I want to emit sound at a particular frequency from my app for 5 seconds. I am using phonegap to cater to both ios and android. Is there any phonegap api to emit sound at a particular frequency for a specified time?I think in android it is through AudioTrack class that helps to do this.

Comment: What are your target platforms? If available, Web Audio API should do exactly that.

Comment: @VladStirbu The target platforms are ios and android.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are no API/plugin that I could find @ram mere. What we did is to record the sound at the particular frequency and use the media plugin to play the sound. That worked for us.